# How can I display date in dd-mm-yyyy format with a leading zero when day or month is less than 10?

Tags: c

I am trying to save current date on a variable with the following format: 0301 (day and month).
I am using time function and the only problem I come across is that I can't seem to find a way to print the date with leading zero. For example, I can only print 31 instead of 0301.
Are there any ways to fix it?

I used itoa() function to turn the integer of the day and month into 2 separate strings and then tried to edit the string characters separately but I couldn't manage to do so.

Comment: Check any documentation for `sprintf` format specifiers. `%02d` will do what you want.

Comment: `itoa` can't do this.  (Also `itoa` isn't standard, so `sprintf` is a better choice on two different counts.)

Comment: If you use `struct tm` from `<time.h>`, you'd use [`strftime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html). However, judging from your description, you're working with ad hoc data so you should use the [`sprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html) family of functions. You should show us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) — the same idea by a different name).

Comment: Aside: Instead of "dd-mm-yyyy", consider standard [YYYY-MM-DD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a combination of localtime and strftime functions (from time.h)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm *info;
  char buffer [1024];

  time (&rawtime);
  info = localtime (&rawtime);
  strftime (buffer, sizeof (buffer), "%d%m", info);
  printf ("time: %s\n", buffer);
return 0;
}
```

Here are the sources I used:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_localtime.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm

This are better sources (thanks to [@phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74994136/how-can-i-display-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-with-a-leading-zero-when-day-or-mont/74995148?noredirect=1#comment132344313_74995148) for point it out):

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime

Comment: tutorialspoint is definitely not a source. It's just some shitty tutorial with advertisements. Only https://en.cppreference.com/w/c is reliable with authoritative sources

Comment: Personally I don't use it very often but in this case it is useful (besides, it is the first result you get if you search for strftime in google)